# How to convert ArrayList to SortedList in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist, type-conversion, sortedlist

I want to convert an ArrayList to SortedList in Java. How can I do it? When I run the following code, I get the error "java.base/java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to javafx.base@10.0.1/javafx.collections.transformation.SortedList."

```
 SortedList<Entity> entitiesList = (SortedList<Entity>)Stream.concat(eventsList.stream(), timeXsList.stream())
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

eventsList and timeXsList are two arraylists of type Entity.

Comment: casting doesn't change the type of an object. It only changes the type of the variable, provided that the object is assignable to this type. In your case, `SortedList`  needs to wrap an `ObservableList`, so you need one of those

Answer (score 0):

```
SortedList<Entity> entitiesList = new SortedList<>(
    FXCollections.observableArrayList(eventsList));
```